# AJAX does not return anticipated response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, circular-queue

I'm trying to start to use AJAX to

1. send a Javascript variable from one PHP file to another
2. that will enqueue it to a queue function I have created
3. and then peek that ID in the queue by changing the < p > tag in my main file

**EDIT:**

I get an error now that I have added an error parameter; either `[Object Object]` or `Undefined` and `console.log(data)` the error is a `POST 500 jquery.js`

I have tried solutions to add `.d` after `data`, altering the `dataType` to match the response from the Networks panel in Dev Tools, `json_encode` in the PHP file, but no luck.

Javascript:

```js
var log = document.getElementById("log"); //ID of the  <p> tag to change to ID number

document.getElementById("scanButton".addEventListener("click", async () => {

try{

/*functions to obtain ID number*/

var IDnumber = 0000; //functions will change this value after every click



$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "savetodb.php", 
    data: { idNumber : IDnumber },
    success: function(data){
        log.innerHTML = data;
    },
    error: function(error) {
        log.innerHTML = error;
    }
  });
  
  
  
} catch (error){
      log.innerHTML = error;
});
```

PHP:

```
$idNumber = $_POST['idNumber'];

/*queue methods and functions*/

public function peek() { 
  return $this->queue[$this->front]; 
}

$queue = new CircularQueue(15);
$queue->enqueue($idNumber);
echo $queue->peek();
```

[image: Networking Page in DevTools for savetodb.php]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to catch error through parameter "error" instead of using try catch.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "savetodb.php", 
    data: { idNumber : IDnumber}, 
    success: function(){
        log.innerHTML = ("ID : " + IDnumber + " logged successfully!");}
    },
    error: function(error) {
        log.innerHTML = error.responseText;
    }
);
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/